# Como puedo inclinar o poner horizontal escalas del eje x en un grafico incrustado en Tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas

Como dijo el dermatólogo directo al grano.Tengo una ejercicio que maneja datos de tiempo y debo hacer dos graficas, una incrustada en tkinter y otra en la ventana externa de genera Matplotlib. Al graficar la ventana externa obtengo la grafica que quiero, pero al graficar la incrustada en tkinter como las fechas son largas se subreponen, necesito inclinar o poner en horizontal los títulos del eje X pero no encuentro la manera. Abajo dejo el código que elaboré.

Seguro de contar con ayuda o comentarios les anticipo mi agradecimiento.

Saludosssss.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector

class Ventana(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, width=800, height=500)
        self.master=master
        self.pack()
        self.crear_widgets()

    def crear_widgets(self):
        self.frame1=Frame(self, bg="#bfdaff")
        self.frame1.place(x=50, y=20, width=500, height=400)
        Button(self, text='VER DATOS',  command=self.graficarentkinter).place(x=500,y=450)
        Button(self, text='EXTRAER GRAF', command=self.graficarfueratkinter).place(x=620, y=450)

    def Series(self):
        weight = [83, 86, 84, 82, 77]   #Lista de pesos
        dateStr = ['2021-12-25', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-07', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'] 
        dateObj = [date.fromisoformat(d) for d in dateStr] 
        return pd.Series(weight, index=dateObj) 

    def graficarentkinter(self):
        fig = mpl.figure.Figure([6,4])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.frame1)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        plot1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
        plot1.plot(self.Series())
        canvas.draw()
            
    def graficarfueratkinter(self):
        self.Series().plot()
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
        plt.show()

    def obtener_datos(self):
        pass


def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.wm_title("Practica graficas")
    app=Ventana(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: ¿por qué no aumentar el width de Frame1 a 600 por ejemplo?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Sí sería una alternativa, sin embargo, como la aplicación está pensada que mostrar más información y posiblemente incluir la hora tarde o temprano se van a sobreponer. Es por ese motivo que necesito específicamente inclinar o poner en horizontal. Saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Para hacerlo puedes utilizar [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html), hay otras formas de hacerlo, pero como estas utilizando subplots y axes, lo más fácil es utilizar esta función.

Un punto importante es que [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) devuelve `axes` no `plots` por lo que cambié el nombre de tu variable `plot1` por `ax` para que el código sea consistente con la documentación. Dicho esto, lo único que hay que hacer es configurar la rotación en las etiquetas del eje "x":

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 45)
```

Al hacer únicamente esto, vas a darte cuenta que las etiquetas están rotadas, pero ahora se "cortan" ya que se salen un poco del gráfico, para arreglar esto es necesario configurar el tipo de `layout` que se va a utilizar, esto se configura en `Figure` y utilizamos el método compacto (`tight`)

```
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
```

Y un cambio más que hice a tu código es configurar el tamaño de la figura y utilizar el argumento `dpi` (Dots per inch, [documentación](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html)) para que la gráfica utilice el canvas completo

```
fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
```

Ejemplo completo (Comenté mysql porque no se utiliza para reproducir el error y aplicar la solución, si la necesitas en otra parte de tu código entonces quita el `#`):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from tkinter import *
#import mysql.connector

class Ventana(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, width=800, height=500)
        self.master=master
        self.pack()
        self.crear_widgets()

    def crear_widgets(self):
        self.frame1=Frame(self, bg="#bfdaff")
        self.frame1.place(x=50, y=20, width=500, height=400)
        Button(self, text='VER DATOS',  command=self.graficarentkinter).place(x=500,y=450)
        Button(self, text='EXTRAER GRAF', command=self.graficarfueratkinter).place(x=620, y=450)

    def Series(self):
        weight = [83, 86, 84, 82, 77]   #Lista de pesos
        dateStr = ['2021-12-25', '2021-12-31', '2022-01-07', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'] 
        dateObj = [date.fromisoformat(d) for d in dateStr] 
        return pd.Series(weight, index=dateObj) 

    def graficarentkinter(self):
        # Modifiqué figsize y dpi para que la gráfica abarcara completamente el canvas
        fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=100)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.frame1)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        # Cambié plot1 por ax, la función fig.add_subplot() regresa axes, no plots
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
        ax.plot(self.Series())
        # Configurar la rotación para el eje X a 45°
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 45)
        # Configurar "tight layout" para que las etiquetas del eje X no se corten
        fig.set_tight_layout(True)
        canvas.draw()
            
    def graficarfueratkinter(self):
        self.Series().plot()
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
        plt.show()

    def obtener_datos(self):
        pass


def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.wm_title("Practica graficas")
    app=Ventana(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica en `tkinter`:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: Genial!! quedo perfecto. Quedo muy agradecido por tu ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!